# Como obtener desde la base de datos MySQL el nombre del usuario que ha iniciado sesión utilizando php en Android Studio

Tags: php, java, mysql, android

que tal estais, me gustaria saber como puedo obtener desde la base de datos el nombre del usuario que ha iniciado sesion y mostrarlo en un textview en otras actividades.

He intentado con este codigo para obtener el nombre desde la actividad del login:

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
in.putExtra("user_name", nombre_usuario);
startActivity(in);
```

Y este para obtenerlo en otra actividad:

```
String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre_usuario");
```

Ahora bien, ese metodo funciona perfectamente, pero desde que cierro y abro la app se borran esos datos, la app te permite guardar la session, si cierras y abre la app ya el nombre del usuario no existe, me gustaria ver si ahi un metodo para que sea dinamico, obtenerlo desde la base de datos directamente, por cierto estoy utilizando Volley en mi projecto Gracias !

Comment: Segun el código `in.putExtra("user_name", nombre_usuario);` tienes que utilizar `user_name` en la siguiente actividad para obtener el valor pero estas utilizando `getStringExtra("nombre_usuario")`, debes de cambiarla a `getStringExtra("user_name")`

Comment: Siii @RobertoEMoran, osea simplemente puse un ejemplo, en mi codigo esta de la manera correcta, pero al reiniciar la app ese valor se pierde

Comment: Claramente se va a perder si el dato no es persistente o no lo almacenas en algún lado. Lo que te recomiendo es que almacenes el dato en algún lado, como ser una `Preferencia`, dejaré un ejemplo:

Comment: Lo que sucede es que si la aplicación se reinicia o el sistema le reclama la memoria por no estar siendo utilizada todos los datos en memoria se perderán, investiga el método `onSaveInstanceState` y `onRestoreInstanceState` que son los que se utilizan para guardar datos temporales en caso ocurra un reinicio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, vamos a suponer que tiene un `LogIn` como pantalla principal el cuál solo se visualiza cuando el usuario borra los datos de la aplicación o cierra sesión. Entonces, partiendo desde ahí sabemos que habrá un `EditText` en donde se ingresará el usuario:

```
EditText usuario = findViewById(R.id.etUsuario);
```

Ahora, sabemos que hay un botón de inicio de sesión:

```
Button iniciarSesion = findViewById(R.id.btnInicioSesion);
```

Para hacer el dato persistente, en este caso al ser un único dato, dispondré de usar una `Preferencia`. Vamos a crearla con el nombre `PreferenciaUsuario` y sería algo como esto:

```
public class PreferenciaUsuario {
    private final Context contexto;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public PreferenciaUsuario(Context contexto){
        this.contexto = contexto;
    }

    public void guardarValorUsuario(String valor){
        sharedPreferences = contexto.getSharedPreferences("usuario", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("nombre", valor);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String traerEseValor(){
        sharedPreferences = contexto.getSharedPreferences("usuario", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString("nombre", "");
    }
}
```

Ahora, en tu botón luego de hacer el `Request` y demás deberemos usar la preferencia:

```
//yo estoy usando un Fragment pero aplica igual para una activity
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    ini = view.findViewById(R.id.btnIniciarLogin);
    ini.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        new PreferenciaUsuario(getContext()).guardarValorUsuario(etusuario.getText().ToString());
    });
    return view;
}
```

Y donde sea que quieras mostrar el nombre, supongamos un `TextView` simplemente llamas al otro método:

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tvUsuario);
String user = new PreferenciaUsuario(getContext()).traerEseValor();
tv.setText(user)
```

Y con eso ya lo visualizarías.

Comment: Mil gracias compañero ! , Funciono

Comment: Me alegro que te haya sido útil